# Standard Behaviour for mix of 'ON-DELETE-CASCADE' and 'ON-DELETE-RESTRICT' constraints in Mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, delete, sql-standard, cascade

In **mysql 5.6**, Consider these 2 examples creating relationships between A, B, C and D.

**Example 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `d` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES c (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO d VALUES (1, 1, 1);

DELETE FROM a;
```

The result is that all rows are deleted.

**Example 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `d` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES c (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO d VALUES (1, 1, 1);

DELETE FROM a;
```

Notice that the only difference is the change of what foreign key is **RESTRICT** from **d**. This example however, fails with

> Error Code: 1451
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hello`.`d`, CONSTRAINT `d_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`))

While logically, it's the same as **Example 1**. Without having looked at the source code of **MySQL**, I strongly suspect that the foreign keys are "applied" in lexical order based on their name. **What will be the standard behaviour (ANSI-SQL) in this scenario?**

Comment: *I strongly suspect that the foreign keys are "applied" in lexical order based on their name.* Of course. The only alternative is random order, but it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Akina, can you elaborate this behaviour in Postgres?

Comment: @Akina, 'lexical order based on their name' mean 'Iexical order of table names' , am I right?

Comment: *'lexical order based on their name' mean 'Iexical order of table names' , am I right?* I cannot find any direct reference in user manual... except [InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html): *InnoDB performs cascading operations through a **depth-first algorithm**, based on records in the indexes corresponding to the foreign key constraints.* This can explain (to self at least) why the first code succeeded whereas second one fails. Simply assume that the chained actions calculated for a table are calculated once.

Comment: I don't know what the standard says, but I tested the first example with Db2 V11.1.4.4, and Db2 does not allow creation of table D because of: `SQL20255N  FOREIGN KEY "ID..." is not valid because it would cause a 
descendent table "DB2INST1.D" to be delete-connected to its ancestor table 
"DB2INST1.A" through multiple relationships with conflicting delete rules. The 
conflict is between the delete rules of constraints "DB2INST1.D.SQL190429125" 
and "DB2INST1.D.ID..." on the descendent table. Reason code = "3".  
SQLSTATE=42915`

Comment: Example 2 is not allowed either, for the same reason

Comment: @Akina, the order in which they are created (create time) may be a possible alternative to lexical order

Comment: @Lennart Swap whole FK lines in 1st test (`c` before `b`)...

Comment: @Akina, I was not referring how it's actually done, just pointing out that there are other possibilities than ordering constraints lexicographical. Besides, changing the order of constraints inside a create table statement may or may not change the order in which they are created. I suggest creating them with alter table and wait a while to see if it matters

Comment: Sometimes FKs are more hassle then they are worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified example 1 so that the syntax is accepted by all vendors that I tried. It turns out that the only DBMS of the tested ones that reject the scenario is Db2 [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b4218363846761e9f02707e16f8ec02d):

```
MariaDB 10.2, 10.3 Yes
MySQL 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 Yes
Postgres 11 Yes

Oracle 11g release 2, 18 Yes
SQLServer 2017 Yes
Db2 V11 No
```

Note that the foreign keys have to be slightly modified for Oracle and SQLServer. See links provided by [Dinesh Kumar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/154486/dinesh-kumar)

[Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c18f8e4fa2f481b9c39314321eddba62)
[SQLServer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b553c95643ccbae02077ff2dea559fb3)

Db2 throws an exception like:

SQL20255N  FOREIGN KEY .. is not valid because it would cause a descendent table ... to be delete-connected to its ancestor table ... through multiple relationships with conflicting delete rules. The conflict is between the delete rules of constraints ... and ... on the descendent table. Reason code = "3".  SQLSTATE=42915 SQLCODE=-20255

I skimmed through 7IWD2-02-Foundation-2011-12.pdf which can be download from:

http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip

but I did not find anything mentioned regarding this.

To me, it seems as if Db2 behave sanely in this regard, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: seems like Oracle 11g [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c18f8e4fa2f481b9c39314321eddba62), and SQL Server [link] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b553c95643ccbae02077ff2dea559fb3) is allowing this case, but db2 throws exception. [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=12bf2f426575318db7b093930585717b).. Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Your link for Oracle misses `ON DELETE RESTRICT` in table d and your link for SQL server uses `ON DELETE NO ACTION` for the same table. The link for Db2 contains an error before what was discussed here. I'm not sure what I am supposed to update in my answer?

Comment: Oracle by default takes it to 'ON DELETE RESTRICT' ,if no action is specified, and SQL server uses 'ON DELETE NO ACTION' clause for restrict behaviour (I think there is no such clause 'ON DELETE RESTRICT' in SQL server). You have mentioned that Oracle, SqlServer won't allow this case, but they allow it actually

Comment: I'll check it out later

Comment: @DineshKumar, updated answer, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: if you find time, can you please explain the exception thrown by db2 server in short.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93498/discussion-between-dinesh-kumar-and-lennart).