# Same column present on two or more foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, foreign-key, mysql-8.0

A simple schema leading to my question is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    AID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE A_COPY (
    AID INT,
    CID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (AID, CID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES A(AID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE R (
    AID INT,
    CID INT,
    EXTRANUM INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (AID, CID, EXTRANUM),
    FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES A(AID) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (AID, CID) REFERENCES A_COPY(AID, CID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

*[This SQL Fiddle contains sample data and queries along with the schema shown above.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bed7b/1)*

Here, as you can see, we build up on the `A` table by extending it (say that `A_COPY` is a "weak entity" in an Entity Relationship diagram) and then use it in some relation `R`. The question is, that here (table `R`) we use two different foreign key constraints where one column is the same in both constraints. That might, or might not be meaningful.

So, one thing is whether this would be meaningful. I believe it would, since I might (for some reason) want to opt for different foreign key referential actions when deleting from table `A` or `A_COPY` respectively, as shown here.

The second question is **how** do these statements get implemented in MySQL with InnoDB tables. Generally, the question is: what is the chosen rule for foreign key constraints on the same table with two or more identical columns part of the respective foreign key constraints (e.g. here `AID` is used identically in **two** foreign key constraints on the same table `R`)?

Comment: When in doubt, use application code instead of `FOREIGN KEYs`, `TRIGGERs`, etc.  Meanwhile, did you intend to have `extranum` as part of the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, it is just something extra, probably another foreign key in another table, my intent was not to make it fully useful, only study the technical effect. And yes, I am wondering if there is any related documented behaviour.

Comment: Why does R have a FK to both A and A_COPY when the FK to A_COPY will ensure  that it also meets the requirements of the FK to A

Comment: @JoeW because of the ability, if given by the RDBMS, to act on a different referential action to some of these two. That is exactly the point of the whole question, what the technical specification does.

Comment: I think there is a difference in having the same column in multiple FK's and having a FK to one table and a different FK that duplicates the FK that the other table also has. For example having a FK on columns A,B and one on A,C because they go to different tables instead of one on A,B and A alone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what the standard says about this, but clearly, there is a conflict between:

```
  a) FOREIGN KEY (AID) REFERENCES A(AID) ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

and

```
  b) FOREIGN KEY (AID, CID) REFERENCES A_COPY(AID, CID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The final result may differ if a) is evaluated before b) or the other way around. There is a similar question in [standard-behaviour-for-mix-of-on-delete-cascade-and-on-delete-restrict-const](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/236911/standard-behaviour-for-mix-of-on-delete-cascade-and-on-delete-restrict-const/236927#236927)

Answer (score 0):

A `FOREIGN KEY` does these things:

- Tell humans how the schema designer expects tables to be tied together.
- Do integrity checks when `INSERTing` -- to verify that the corresponding row exists.
- Do `CASCADE` things when `UPDATEing` or `DELETEing`.
- Provide an `INDEX` -- if one does not already exist -- to facilitate the lookup needed for the integrity or cascade.

Since you seem to have two conflicting `CASCADE` requirements, there may be a rule described deep in the bowels of the documentation.  I would *guess* that the FK actions are performed in the order written.  Hence `ON DELETE NO ACTION` would do nothing, then `ON DELETE CASCADE` would take over.

In my opinion, FKs are very simple minded; expecting more than trivial actions from them is risky.  This forum is littered with Questions asking "can I write an FK to do blah".  The answer is usually "no".

You are asking a corollary question "what happens in this weird case".  My answer is "Don't trust MySQL, use app code to do whatever you want."  (And you might embody that "business logic" in a Stored Routine.)

Beware of asking too much from Triggers, too.

Comment: First of all, `ON DELETE NO ACTION` does not "do nothing", it acts like `RESTRICT`. Secondly, that's the point of this question: finding what it does technically, which probably here means "how" it does.

Comment: What does "tied together" mean & how does it mean anything other than that the other bullets apply?

Comment: @philipxy - Nothing, other that there is likely to be a `JOIN` on that column.